# Is airbending visible to others in-world?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

Air which is subject to airbending is depicted visually so the audience could follow along:

[image: Air funnel]

Some events imply that the air remains invisible even when subject to bending, such as when Aang blows Toph (in the form of The Blind Bandit) out of the ring in Earth Rumble IV. It takes people a while to realize that there was no contact with earth which led them to suspect The Blind Bandit threw the game. A very strong blast of wind is shown which looks nothing like earthbending.

On the other hand, some scenes imply that it is visible. In the above screenshot, Aang prepares a funnel to launch coal, and his friends know exactly where to drop the coal despite the opening to the funnel being behind his head and to the right. Is there canonical evidence which suggests whether or not airbending is visible (at least to non-airbenders)?

Comment: There was also the scene with the fake airbending, which could imply that the fire nation guards saw an airbending-specific thing and not just some random wind, but since they thought that Momo was the one doing it, it actually just means that they're very dumb. ;)

Comment: @FabianRöling Given that Katara was trying to trick them into thinking she was an earthbender, I have a feeling they were just dumb! Actually, that's would point to airbending _not_ being visible, since Aang was convinced that the Fire Nation could not distinguish between a boulder being lifted with air or earth.